# Use a struct that belongs to another package in Golang

Tags: go, package

In my package main, I have:

```
type InfoToSend struct {
    id      string
    field1        string
    field2        string
}
```

and I call a method send:

```
err = rpc.SendValue(toSend.id, toSend.field1, toSend.field2)
```

I would like to refactor it to:

```
err = rpc.SendValue(toSend)
```

But in the `rpc` package, I cannot access the main.InfoToSend struct.

```
func SendValue(info InfoToSend) error {
...
}
```

What can do about it ?

Comment: You can create another package where you would define your sharable functionality or simply create a package where you will define your sharable models/types. So under your main application, you will have a dir/package "models" and define your type there `InfoToSend` and you can reuse it in your `rpc` package `models.InfoToSend`

Comment: Package `main` is not importable, so you need to move `InfoToSend` to `rpc` and use it there directly or you can declare it in another *importable*, i.e. non-main package and have `rpc` and `main` import that package.

Comment: @mkopriva ah ok, this is why, thanks both, both solution works, but I will go with mkopriva solution, as I have only one model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this logically. What domain does this belong to:

```
type InfoToSend struct {
    id            string
    field1        string
    field2        string
}
```

Does it belong to `main`, or `rpc`. It's info to be sent, hence its name `InfoToSend`. Over what is this info going to be sent? Well, it's part of a remote procedure call it seems. Common sense would place this type in the `rpc` package, then, surely.

The solution, then, is simple, move the type to the `rpc` package and export the type + fields:

```
type InfoToSend struct {
    ID            string
    Field1        string
    Field2        string
}
```

Then, from your main package, simply write this in your `main` package:

```
err := rpc.SendValue(InfoToSend{
    ID:     "id",
    Field1: "field 1 value",
    Field2: "field 2 value",
})
```

Job done.

Comment: yep, this is what I did. Your answer is pretty nice, but I will wait a bit to @mkopriva to publish an answer, as he gave me this answer as comment.

Comment: Silly nitpick but in Go identifiers are not "public" or "private", they are "exported" or "unexported".

Comment: @Adrian: True, usually I'm the pedantic one :P